# safely check for auth.currentUser.email - firebase - react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am getting a email undefined error and would like to know how to safely check if i have  auth.currentUser.email and then if so check if it matches props.email without crashing the project?

```
{auth.currentUser.email === props.email ? ( 

      <button 
             onClick={() => deleteSchedule()}
         
            style={{height:"3vh", width:"30%", 
          // marginTop:"1vh",
     backgroundColor:"black",
     color:"white",

         }}>
           Delete
         </button>  

 ):(
 null
)}
```

Comment: 1) [auth.currentUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.auth.Auth#currentuser) isn't always an object. It can be null. 2) There is no obligation for a user object to have an [email](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.User#email) property. It can also be null.  You need to check for both of these cases like you would any other null check in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As Doug commented, you'll want to first check whether there is a current user, before checking their email:

```
{auth.currentUser && auth.currentUser.email === props.email ? ( 
  ...
```

In general, it's best to react to changes in the auth state, as shown in the first code snippet in the documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) combined with for example a [`useState` hook](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState).